# Navigation Controller with Show relationship

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, navigation, show

I would like to SHOW the view when I click on a specific icon in the Tab bar. Currently the view is PRESENTED, not PUSHED.  I can't access to properties via the main storyboard, I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For **presenting** a controller, the `segue` type should be : **`Present Modally`**

For **pushing** the controller in `navigation stack`, the `segue` type is : **Show**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I already know that. The problem is that I don't have access to change that parameters ...

Comment: Tap on the segue and it will be available in attributes inspector. I just checked it. It is working on my side.

Comment: It's working if I'm on a normal Segue, but not on a Segue from the tab bar .. http://hpics.li/a24bec5

Comment: In tab bar, segue type is "view controllers". You cannot maintain a navigation stack of different tabs in a tab bar. So push cannot be used in this case. Although, you can maintain navigation stack for individual tabs.

Comment: I would like to use the same effect than Instagram. When I click on the picture Icon, The view comes from the bottom (eg Push) ... It's more difficult than I thought ...

Comment: Try using custom animation for that. You can refer to: https://github.com/pgpt10/Custom-Animator